# Hardlinked windows 10. Issues with windows updates and all standart metro apps

Tags: windows, windows-10, ntfs, hardlink

I have installed the fresh windows 10 and created hardlinks:

C:\Program Files -> D:\ProgramFiles

C:\Program Files(x86) -> D:\ProgramFiles(x86)

C:\User -> D:\Users

C:\ProgramData -> D:\ProgramData

The reason for this is obvious for laptop configuration: 
SSD 128gb as a system only! 
HDD 512gb for the rest.

Unfortunately, the OS, as a result, become unstable. I cannot run any standard Metro apps and Windows Updates won't install. However, the biggest issue is MSSQL management studio it simply fails during installation without any error.

I'm wondering whether anyone was able to create a stable system with hardlinks.

Comment: What you want is not fully supported by Microsoft.  If you want to install UWP applications on another storage device, use the user interface to change the storage location, changing the profile location does break UWP applications otherwise.

Comment: Actually I don't need UWP apps at all. I can live without them. What I really need is windows updates to be installed correctly without issues. Am I right in understanding that the core problem is with C:\Users folder ?